# Develop a Wii U game without official dev kit

Tags: unity, wii

I was looking for unity for Wii U game development. But it seems that I need the approval of Nintendo to have the software (and special hardware) (ref: https://wiiu-developers.nintendo.com).

Is there a way to have the software and to replace the hard with an emulator ?

I just want to make a game for fun, I can't afford the official SDK (Rumors says it about $5000)

If it is possible, I would love to have some ressources (I couldn't find anything...)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a question best answered by Nintendo themselves. I have a suspicion that Nintendo isn't interested in people making games just for fun, since it can potentially hurt the Nintendo trademark. They want the name Nintendo be associated with quality, or seemingly quality.

Comment: I don't want to release anything on their shop without their approval, I just want to try a concept of game for Wii U that I have in mind. It can't hurt their trademark...

Comment: They don't know that, and there is no way for them to make sure you don't release a game for free for instance. I don't agree with them mind you. I'm just extrapolating on their reasons.

Comment: What about the apple store or google play ? You can develop what you want but you need an approval to release. The more developers you have, bigger chances are that you end up with great games, right ?

Comment: I guess I won't be able to try so... thanks for your help

Comment: It's also important to keep in mind that the development kit provides insight into the OS, APIs, and device firmware that Nintendo doesn't want being public knowledge because it can disclose information that can be used for a variety of security vulnerability exploits. It really simplifies creating exploits when you know potentially dangerous API calls games have access to. That's one of the (many) reasons the SDKs are under NDA.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention:

Since I posted this question, I went on the official website to register as an "official" developer.

I could get their approval in less than a month.

I think the commercial situation of the WiiU is so bad that they are ready to let anyone try to make great games.

But I still need to buy or rent dev material which is a bit expensive for non professionnal (I am not allowed to disclose the price, sorry)